# Revert Eclipse perspective

Tags: java, eclipse

I somehow screwed up my perspectives and I want to reset them, however the reset button is grayed out. Does anybody know what would cause this?

[image]

I wish I had more information but this is really all I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the Window menu => Reset Perspective.

**EDIT:**

The option may be under Window => Perspective => Reset Perspective, depending on the Eclipse version.

Comment: Isn't it actually _Window -> Perspectives... -> Reset Perspective_?

Comment: @tobias_k Not sure if the exact option differs between versions but it should be close to this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the "Revert" button in the preferences is grayed out, or why it is called "Revert" instead of "Reset", but you can reset the perspective by clicking the "Reset" menu item in the context menu of the perspective in the perspectives menu bar (usually in the top-right corner).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the top menu in Eclipse select the Window-Perspective-Reset Perspective. That will bring back the default setting.